# Building an Oauth2 API service, what is the use of client_secret

Tags: web-services, api, oauth-2.0

Good morning, we are a little company in Europe, and we need to set up some webservice for internal and external use. We decided to implement an autentication to those webservices, and i though to implement an Oath2 authentication. The problem is the following (besides the fact that i've only used the Oauth2 standard one time) that i do not really understand the use of the "client_secret", from the point of view of the service provider. Isn't the client_id enough to identify a client? Why is the client_secret needed exactly and how is it to be implemented in the general logic of the application?

Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that the client requesting credentials is who you think they are, and the client ID is used in requests that users can see (in the URL). Without a client secret anybody could pretend to be any client application to trick users into granting access.